# Are there mapping/graphing front ends that can call the Socrata API?

Tags: mapping, socrata, opendata

How complex a project would this be?
There is the issue of integrating the dataset specific API.
  I.e. dataset column names, dataset metadata perhaps
There is the issue of integration higher level APIs.
  I.e names of datasets available, information about the specific portal, ...

Am I missing the point here with my question?  
Or would this a major coding project?

RLH

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options you might take a look at:

- You can actually create maps from Socrata data right from within our data exploration tools. Here's [a support article](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202950558-Use-geospatial-data-on-the-Socrata-platform-) on how you can do so
- Using the [GeoJSON](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/formats/geojson.html) output from our API, you can pull data into tools like [CartoDB](https://cartodb.com/) without needing to download it first
- You could create a map mashup using a library like [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or the Google Maps API. Here's an [example of how to do it with the Google Maps API](http://dev.socrata.com/consumers/examples/google-maps.html)